# Why is node-sass --watch breaking the build (but only on Linux)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, node-sass

With `node-sass --watch`, I'm expecting a CSS rebuild every time I save out a change to my styling. And indeed the rebuild appears to be working correctly; but reloading the site reveals that the CSS is completely broken.

This is quite a pain, because I have to stop and restart my dev server every time I make a style change. It works just fine on my colleages' computers (they both use macOS); it's only on mine (Ubuntu 18.04) that it fails.

What painfully obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Good grief, but I've been silly; the issue was actually with a buggy version of postcss-cli, which was meant to grab the raw CSS produced by node-sass. Upgrading fixed the issue.